# JS Unit test for prototype methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Because trim() is not supported in IE8 i want to have a fall back option to use a regexp (many examples on here i know), so have this

```
function trim(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (String.prototype.trim) {
      value = value.trim();
    } else {
      value = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }
  }

  return value;
}
```

What i want to be able to do is write unit tests for this, so basically having `String.prototype.trim` set to `true` or `false` so that i can ensure that native and regexp options are used

```
describe('trim', function() {
  it('should use native trim if available', function(){
    String.prototype.trim = true; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    var string = 'test string  ';
    expect(string.trim()).toEqual('test string');
  });  
});
```

How can i go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, you are reassigning String.prototype.trim to a boolean. This means that you can no longer call string.trim().

You could check if your polyfill works by assigning String.prototype.trim to false, and then calling trim(string).

```
describe('trim', function() {
  it('should use native trim if available', function(){
    String.prototype.trim = false;
     var string = 'test string  ';
    expect(trim(string)).toEqual('test string');
  });  
});
```

I'm quite uncomfortable with reassigning properties of String, so alternately you could break the ie8 trim into a separate function, which you can then test more easily.

```
function ie8Trim(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
   return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
  }
  return value
}

function trim(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (String.prototype.trim) {
      return value.trim();
    } else {
      return ie8Trim(value)
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I have gone with because as you say, splitting it out into separate functions makes it easier to test

Answer (score 0):

you have at least two options:

1. test whole method (not just `String.prototype.trim`) in different browsers. that's the recommended way. your code WILL run in different browsers and you should test it there
2. if for any reason you can't/don't want to test in different browsers, you can use IOC and higher order functions: build function that takes `true/false` and returns a function that trims a string. and then test if this function works correctly in both cases. and on production as an input param you use `String.prototype.trim`

you can also change the prototype of built-in function (AFAIK this not always works because of security reasons) but it's dangerous because you don't (or it's easy to miss) know which built-in functions are used by your testing framework and libraries and code you use in your tests. so don't do it